# (SQL) problem with subtracting 48 hours from date in live SQL oracle

Tags: sql, date, plsql

I have table Flight and need to compute check_in before departure (-48 hours, so 2 days before departure) in Live SQL. I have no idea how to do it. Thank you very so much everyone!

```
     crate table Flight (
                  number_flight varchar2(10),
                  departure date,
                  arrival date,
                  check_in Check_in);



    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Check_In AS OBJECT (
        departure DATE,
        MEMBER FUNCTION comput_check_in RETURN date?
    ) NOT FINAL;


    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY Check_In AS
        MEMBER FUNCTION comput_check_in RETURN date? AS
    BEGIN
        RETURN  DATEADD('hour' , -48 , departure) ;
    END;

insert into flight values ('AA1234',
                       to_date('26/MAR/2020 03:10 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI AM'),
                       to_date('27/MAR/2020 09:30 AM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI AM'), 
                       comput_check_in(to_date('26/MAR/2020 03:10 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI AM'))));
     select * from Flight
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle has a `-` operator between a date and a number representing the days to subtract:

```
INSERT INTO flight VALUES
('AA1234',
 TO_DATE('26/MAR/2020 03:10 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI AM'),
 TO_DATE('27/MAR/2020 09:30 AM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI AM'), 
 TO_DATE('26/MAR/2020 03:10 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI AM') - 2 -- Here!
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the requirement is that check-in should always be 2 days prior to departure, then you can define it as a virtual column and leave the whole thing to the database:

```
create table flight
( number_flight  varchar2(10) constraint flight_pk primary key
, departure      date
, arrival        date
, check_in       as (departure -2) );

insert into flight
( number_flight
, departure
, arrival )
values
( 'FR8321'
, to_date('2020-05-14 07:15', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
, to_date('2020-05-14 10:45', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') );

select * from flight;

NUMBER_FLIGHT DEPARTURE         ARRIVAL           CHECK_IN
------------- ----------------- ----------------- -----------------
FR8321        14-MAY-2020 07:15 14-MAY-2020 10:45 12-MAY-2020 07:15
```